# What is this gigantic high-tech cylinder in the corner of a middle-class Chinese family's living/dining room in Shanghai?

Tags: power-electronics, consumer-electronics

[image: screenshot]

My guess is that it has something to do with the climate, but why is it so big and cylinder-shaped? I guess it could actually be a fridge, but it looks too oddly shaped to be that. But maybe. The room doesn't appear to be their kitchen, though, but a separate place where a big table is set for them to eat.

Comment: I am not sure about posting such pictures to the forum with people from the inside of their home and their faces.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it shows the faces of possibly unconsenting people.

Answer (score 2):

It's a guess, but an informed one, based on the 20°C / 68°F indicator on the digital display. One might believe that this is the desired temperature or the current temperature. From there, it's an easy extension to believe that the device is an air conditioner evaporator and distribution unit. As A/C units go, it's a bit on the large side and may be a portable self-contained unit that requires only exhaust air tubes to go to a window or doorway outside.